# ReactNative Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

i'm working on a react-native project V 0.59.5
i'm trying to **uprgrade** it to V 0.63.3
i was trying to solve problems poping in android studio, i updated the android studio to 4.1.1 and then there was a message suggesting to upgrade **gradle to version 4.1.1**, i was using 3.5.3.

i upgraded the grale version and after that i have an error that i cannot solve and i couldn't find useful anser for it. i tried removing cache folder in .gradle folder and restarted android studio but didn't help. changing the gradle version didn't help either.
this is the error:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :react-native-fs
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

i manually changed the gradle to what it was before.

in my **gradle-wrapper.properties** i have :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

and in **build.grale** file i have :

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to upgrade your project's gradle. Although I am not sure if RN 0.63.3 works with gradle 4.1.1. Anyways:

In your build.gradle, set the gradle version to:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1')
```

For this to work you also need to change the distributionUrl to at least 6.5:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

You can look up which gradle version you need for which plugin version:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Also make sure, that in your build.gradle you include the google repository:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
...
```

Btw, I have a react-native 0.63.3 running with using gradle plugin version 4.0.0 and version gradle-6.2.

Comment: i didn't know that i accepted the suggestion by mistake. i have tried this but didn't work. still nagging about gradle v 4.1.1

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have any error logs

Comment: Updated my answer, do you include the google repository?

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using React Native `0.61.5` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2`

Comment: Any solution, I'm also stuck with same issue ??

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was showing same error for
react-native-fetch-blob
Solution:
in your Project just install react-native-fs latest version.

Run the command
npm install react-native-fs --save